# Async methods chaining with DRY and Divide&Conquer principle

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, dry, divide-and-conquer

Assume we have the following method:

```
private async Task<string> Foo(string parameter)
{
    // Some code to convert source parameter
    string convertedParameter = //value;

    CallResult callResult;
    try
    {
        var integerResult = await LoadInformationAsync(convertedParameter);
        if (integerResult > 0)
        {
            callResult = // Some logic to analyse integerResult and generate CallResult object
        }
        else
        {
            callResult = // Some logic to analyse integerResult and generate CallResult object
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        callResult = CallResult.Default; // some default value if call failed
    }

    var stringResult = // some logic to convert callResult instance to some another string result;

    return stringResult; //Finally return the result
}
```

Let's not go deep into the details. The main thing is that this method contains some business logic and call (assume 3d party) method `LoadInformationAsync` that is awaitable.

Behind those comments can be tons of business logic so, I think, everyone will agree that it would be definitely good to split the logic into separate methods(or even classes).

As a result a core-call of  `LoadInformationAsync` method will go deeper into call stack. Something like this:

```
private async Task<string> Foo(string parameter)
{
    // Some code to convert source parameter
    string convertedParameter = //value;

    CallResult callResult = await MakeSafeCall(convertedParameter);

    var stringResult = // some logic to convert callResult instance to some another string result;

    return stringResult; //Finally return the result
}

private async Task<CallResult> MakeSafeCall(string parameter)
{
    try
    {
        var integerResult = await LoadInformationAsync(convertedParameter);
        if (integerResult > 0)
        {
            return callResult = // Some logic to analyse integerResult and generate CallResult object
        }
        else
        {
            return callResult = // Some logic to analyse integerResult and generate CallResult object
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return CallResult.Default;
    }
}
```

As a result we have slightly better code. F.e. is some class/method might want to call method `MakeSafeCall` to have there try/catch.

But what do we have now? We have one extra async method that needs to be awaited. And each pair of async/await brrings a state machine capturing the context and so on. Ok, we can deal with this overhead, but what if we have more complicated logic (and very often we really do) that forces us to split our root method into smaller peaces. Our async/await pairs count will increase. And it seems not to be very good.

So the question: what is the good pattern of using async/await in such situations?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but one good pattern is if you don't need the sync context don't keep the context. Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the layers that don't have functions later on that care about the thread they are running on. It only effects the layer you declare it on, so if you did `await LoadInformationAsync(convertedParameter).ConfigureAwait(false)` then anything after `await MakeSafeCall(` would still keep its sync context but anything between `await LoadInformationAsync(` and the end of the function would not.

Comment: Indeed I do care about the thread, since I`m actively using async/await with UI. But I`ll dig into ConfigureAwait(false) to find out more about this.

Comment: We need to see the code in MakeSafeCall to see what needs to be done. The task may not need be awaited inside it at all.

Comment: In comments it is said that the code after calling LoadInformationAsync uses it`s result, so I assume that it has to be awaited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Stephan Toub has a great answer to your question in his article *[Async Performance: Understanding the Costs of Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx)*

> Asynchronous methods are a powerful productivity tool, enabling you to
>   more easily write scalable and responsive libraries and applications.
>   It’s important to keep in mind, though, that **asynchronicity is not a
>   performance optimization for an individual operation.** Taking a
>   synchronous operation and making it asynchronous will invariably
>   degrade the performance of that one operation, as it still needs to
>   accomplish everything that the synchronous operation did, but now with
>   additional constraints and considerations. A reason you care about
>   asynchronicity, then, is **performance in the aggregate:** how your
>   overall system performs when you write everything asynchronously, such
>   that you can overlap I/O and achieve better system utilization by
>   consuming valuable resources only when they’re actually needed for
>   execution. The asynchronous method implementation provided by the .NET
>   Framework is well-optimized, and often ends up providing as good or
>   better performance than well-written asynchronous implementations
>   using existing patterns and volumes more code. Any time you’re
>   planning to develop asynchronous code in the .NET Framework from now
>   on, asynchronous methods should be your tool of choice.

The bottom line is, don't optimize prematurely. If you benchmark your code and see that an `async` method is a bottleneck, see what its doing behind the covers and how you can write your code to be more performance oriented. But keep in mind that the .NET framework team had this in mind when implementing async-await, you can see that in the details, such as making the [`AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.asynctaskmethodbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) a struct and not a class to reduce GC pressure, etc.

I suggest you read stephans article thoroughly to get a better understanding of the costs/optimizations made by the framework.

Answer (score 1):

The overhead is really negligible, especially when it's surrounded by a lot of business logic. You can try to remove redundant `async-await` calls when there are ones:

Turn:

```
async Task Wait()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

To:

```
Task Wait()
{
    return Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

But don't obsess about that. You would probably never reach the point where that is actually your bottleneck. And if you do, there are many more .Net features that would need to go as well, like `yield` (and most of LINQ with it) or even lambda expressions.

Comment: That is making a hidden assumption that the awaited result wouldn't need to be modified / accessed. Not sure we can assume that based on the OP's question.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It's not an assumption, it's a clarification of "redundant async-await calls". I'm not claiming the OP actually has these in her/his code though.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Im simply not sure the OP can use that in this case.

Comment: yield needs to go? That's funny. I've optimized code single handedly by using yield instead of returning lists for no reason.

Comment: @AndreasMüller both `yield` and `async-await` are huge assets for macro-optimizations, but they do add cost with their state machines. If you reach a point when that cost is too much, you have bigger problems than some extra `await`s

Comment: I would love to see proof on yield beeing subject to macro optimization. For any use case i have seen so far they were by far the most performant solution to the problem. i don't know similar things about async await however.

Comment: @AndreasMüller What do you mean? Macro optimization is optimization, you just said you've optimized code by using `yield`. At the micro level though, using `yield` to iterate over an array is slower than simply increasing an index.

Comment: my bad. i was beeing an idiot. for some reason i understood that to optimize performance greatly you would have to get rid of yield, which is the opposite of what you said. you're right

Comment: Beware that removing async await like this (i.e. where there is a 'return await', is not always equivalent. For example, if your return await is inside a try block, then removing the async/await will cause the task to be returned, bypassing the catch block and causing finally blocks to run immediately.